# Add a new table into the ASP .NET Core MVC app with Identity

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a question about creating a new table in ASP.NET Core MVC application. I've created it with "Individual User Accounts" so I have Identity tables in DB.

How can I create my own tables in this DB? Should I create a new DB Context?

For example: I want to create a tables for students and questions(and their answers).

Comment: Use a different DbContext for your own Tables/Classes.

Comment: @Nikolaus Alright, could you help me with this?Where in ApplicationDbContext.cs should I add a new context? Will be very grateful for any links about this.

Comment: @Алексей you may need to follow this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: As for the comments/answers of others, where is you exact Problem you need to define Classes, used in your DbContext, ... What do you have (Code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already said you used the `Individual User Accounts` Identity template, you can just add your custom models on it, something like:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            //....
        }
    public DbSet<Student> Students{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    //....
    }
```

To add/run migrations after the new changes -- From the Tools Menu locate `Package Console Manager` under `Nuget Console Manager`. Select the project with your ApplicationDbContext and run the commands as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: So, I added those classes and their DbSet . I update database and all seems fine. Where I can find created tables? In SQL Server Obj.Manager I only have Identity tables.

Comment: Did you create/run migrations?

Comment: Nope, could you give some info about this?

Comment: Wow, m8, thanks for your attention and time.You have saved a huge amount of my time. 
P.S. I've tried to use "Add migration" command without '-' so it doesn't work.

Comment: @FelixToo im trying to move from ef6 to efcore but there seems to be a disconnect for me... are there any gd article/links to where to setup organised fluent builder code and what not... ef6 code first seemed better in this regard. Asking as i get the above and hoping you spent more time in this and than me, so perhaps you can show/tell me what works..

Answer (score 2):

1. **Create Your Models**:

   suppose you have the following model:

   ```
   public class Post{

     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}

   }
   ```
2. **in the root directory, create a folder called Persistence (or you can call it whatever you want)**
3. **Inside Persistence folder add a class like this**

   ```
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext {

       public DbSet<Post> Posts {get; set;}
       public MyDbContext((DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base (options)
       {

       }
   }
   ```
4. **Now in the `Startup.cs`, add this line to the `ConfigureServices` function**:

   `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("connStr"));`
5. **Now the Time to create your first migration, by using `dotnet cli`**

> dotnet ef migrations add AddPostsTable --context MyDbContext

Find More At: [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)